# Disable persistence for cache

Tags: ignite

I have enabled persistence in IgniteConfiguration. I have multiple CacheConfigurations. Now  for some cache i want to disable persistence. How can i do it in ignite.
Can you please tell me correct way. I checked there is no api available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this can't be done on a per-cache basis, you can enable/disable persistence for a data region: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memory-configuration#data-regions

If you want to enable persistence for only some of your caches, leaving others in-memory only, you should do the following:

1. Configure two data regions.
2. Enable persistence only for one of the regions.
3. Assign each cache to the appropriate region, based on whether you need persistence for that cache or not.